# Object null right after constructor

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an Android (API level 7) app in Eclipse 3.7.2. I have the most curious problem:

There is a class called `LoginData` to hold login information:

```
public class LoginData {
  private final String login;
  private final String password;

  public LoginData(final String login, final String password) {
    this.login = login;                                      // breakpoint 2 here
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getLogin() {
    return login;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
}
```

Then there is a method to retrieve it (in another class):

```
public static LoginData getLoginData(final Context context) {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs(context);
  final String login = prefs.getString(LOGIN, null);
  final String pass = prefs.getString(PASS, null);
  if (Utils.isEmpty(login) || Utils.isEmpty(pass)) {        // breakpoint 1 here
    return null;
  }
  return new LoginData(login, pass);
}
```

Method isEmpty() looks like this:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String s) {
  return s == null || "".equals(s);
}
```

And a method calling `getLoginData()` inside an `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
protected WSResult doInBackground(final Params... params) {
  final LoginData loginData = Prefs.getLoginData(context);
  ...
```

`context` is an activity in which the async task is located.

Now when I run this code, `loginData` is `null`. Tracing the problem, I put a breakpoint 1 in the specified location. I see that both `login` and `pass` is not empty, and I see the program flow go to the last line, `return new LoginData(...);`. From there it returns... a `null`.

Tracing the problem further I add breakpoint 2, only to find that the constructor `LoginData(...)` does not get invoked.

So my first question is: am I missing something really obvious here? If not, there is some weird problem with the code that gets compiled and run.

Some remarks:

- `LoginData` is used in another location in the program, and works - breakpoint 2 catches on.
- I tried renaming `LoginData` to something else, in case it's cached somewhere or there is a weird name clash.
- I tried running this on a Android 2.1 emulator from Eclipse, as well as on a Galaxy Tab.
- I tried cleaning & building the project again.
- I tried closing & opening the project again.
- I tried deleting the project from workspace and importing it again.

I would like to avoid the necessity to create a new Eclipse workspace (that is my final chance, it helped me in a similar case when dealing with Java EE).

What to do?

Comment: in eclipse I face same problem in listAdpater debugger goes both in if return and also at else return some times ..so please **provide isEmpty function here ** and use SOP once to confirm flow and lo-gin & pass value

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by SOP. I am adding `isEmpty()` code now.

Comment: log.d or System.out.println....

Comment: most likely `Utils.isEmpty()` code will give a clue.

Comment: note, class `Login` has `LoginData` constructor. This would not compile. Do you show us real code?

Comment: if everything you say is correct, then it should not work as it works. so I do suspect either `login` or `pass` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Utils.isEmpty(login) || Utils.isEmpty(pass))
```

try replacing this check with

```
if (login==null || pass==null)
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, as the cause was in `isEmpty()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here but why is the constructor for the "LoginData" class inside of a differently named class("Login")?

Why not have your class be LoginData:

```
public class LoginData
{
    private final String login;
    private final String password;

    public LoginData(final String login, final String password)
    {
        this.login = login;                                      // breakpoint 2 here
        this.password = password;
    }

    //Other Methods
}
```

Comment: My bad, class really has name `LoginData`.

Comment: sure, this would just not compile. most likely a typo in class name. however this is a suspicious sign any way...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was my problem. `Utils.isEmpty()` was being imported from another `Utils` class, which had a bad implementation of `isEmpty()` (basically a negation of the condition).

However, the problem that caused this to take so long was that after hitting breakpoint 1 I didn't see flow go to `return null;`, but rather to `return new LoginData(login, pass);` - this mislead me...

Thanks for help anyone, it *was* a problem in `isEmpty()` after all.